angular oauth oidc login with google does not return user information / token
I wanted to create an example of a simple Google oAuth Sign-in from my Angular application using the Angular oAuth OIDC library (angular-auth-oidc-client (version:17.1.0)). I have set the oAuth configuration and created a login function in my service (google-api.service.ts) function. This is called when you click a button from my app.component.ts. It redirects to Google sign-on successfully on clicking the button, but on successful login I cannot seem to get back to the function initializeGoogleOAuth() subscribe method. It thus cannot redirect to another page after the login succeeds and does not print any logged-in user data.
this.oidcSecurityService.getUserData().subscribe(userData => {

I would also like to know how to access the generated token to pass it into any other API calls afterward as well after login. Can you please point out what is missing from my configuration or authorization call and how I could fix this issue so I can access the logged-in userData?
I have just replaced my real app clientId here with 'app-client-Id-here'
app.module.ts
 AuthModule.forRoot({
      config: {
        authority: 'https://accounts.google.com',
        redirectUrl: window.location.origin,
        postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,
        clientId: '<app-client-Id-here>',
        scope: 'openid profile email',
        responseType: 'code',
        silentRenew: true,
        useRefreshToken: true,
        logLevel: LogLevel.Debug,
      },
    }),


Google-api.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginResponse, OidcSecurityService } from 'angular-auth-oidc-client';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GoogleApiService {

  constructor(private oidcSecurityService: OidcSecurityService) {
   }

   initializeGoogleOAuth(){
     this.oidcSecurityService
      .checkAuth()
      .subscribe((loginResponse: LoginResponse) => {
        const { isAuthenticated, userData, accessToken, idToken, configId } =
          loginResponse;

          if (!isAuthenticated) {
            this.login()
          } else {
            this.oidcSecurityService.getUserData().subscribe(userData => {
              console.log(JSON.stringify(userData));
            })
          }

      });
   }

   getUserData() {
    return this.oidcSecurityService.getUserData()
   }

   login() {
    this.oidcSecurityService.authorize();
  }

  logout() {
    this.oidcSecurityService
      .logoff()
      .subscribe((result) => console.log(result));
  }
}

App.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { GoogleApiService } from './google-api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.scss'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'OAuthOIDC';

  constructor(private googleApiService: GoogleApiService) {

  }

  // called on Button click in app.component.html
  intializeGoogleLogin() {
    this.googleApiService.initializeGoogleOAuth();
  }


} 

Any help would be really appreciated! Thank you!

you can't do this all from frontend... you should read Google's docs: https://developers.google.com/identity/openid-connect/openid-connect
